# Split string into two diff substrings based on a keyword

Tags: java, string, split

So Im trying to split into different lines so it first line is:

```
Aaron123,Nesmith456,Bruno789,Cabo12,Jay21,Smith22 //-- 1st line

Aaron12,Nesmith22,Bruno33,Cabo44,Jay55,Smith66 //-- 2nd line
```

The code I am currently using is:

```
  String s1 =  ("Aaron123,Nesmith456,Bruno789,Cabo12,Jay21,Smith22,Aaron12,Nesmith22,Bruno33,Cabo44,Jay55,Smith66);
   String s[];
    s = s1.split("Aaron");
    System.out.print(s[0]);
```

After doing that code it splits the line but the aaron part of both lines are missing and actually splits into 3 line instead of 2 lines where first line is just empty for some reason so I need help fixing this

Wrong output I get:

```
123,Nesmith456,Bruno789,Cabo12,Jay21,Smith22

12,Nesmith22,Bruno33,Cabo44,Jay55,Smith66
```

The output I want:

```
Aaron123,Nesmith456,Bruno789,Cabo12,Jay21,Smith22 //-- 1st line

Aaron12,Nesmith22,Bruno33,Cabo44,Jay55,Smith66 //-- 2nd line
```

Comment: Is there more efficient way to do it from the beginning then to concatenate at the end?

Answer (score 2):

We can phrase this actually as a split on `,(?=Aaron)`, which splits on comma which is followed by `Aaron`.  Note that `Aaron` will not be *consumed* during the split because we use a lookahead.

```java
String s1 = "Aaron123,Nesmith456,Bruno789,Cabo12,Jay21,Smith22,Aaron12,Nesmith22,Bruno33,Cabo44,Jay55,Smith66";
String[] parts = s1.split(",(?=Aaron)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

This prints:

```
[Aaron123,Nesmith456,Bruno789,Cabo12,Jay21,Smith22,
 Aaron12,Nesmith22,Bruno33,Cabo44,Jay55,Smith66]
```

Comment: My bad I think I worded it wrong output I want is  Aaron123,Nesmith456,Bruno789,Cabo12,Jay21,Smith22 -- 1st line

Aaron12,Nesmith22,Bruno33,Cabo44,Jay55,Smith66 -- 2nd line

Comment: @KNag, The output is correct and so is the code. The code does give you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Use a positive lookahead.  You actually want it to split on `","` but only if the text after the comma is `"Aaron"`.  The corresponding regular expression is `,(?=Aaron)` where the `(?=  )` part means "check that the following text is this, but without incorporating it into the match".

```
s = s1.split(",(?=Aaron)");
```

Comment: OK, no worries.  Proxies do odd things.